# Stargazer tables reporting names of arguments in function, rather than name of variable

Tags: r, r-markdown, lm, stargazer

I'm running a lot of linear models, comparing the results with stargazer, and knitting everything into an html RMarkdown document.

Since I have so many different models to compare, I wrote a function for the basic model and particular set of covariates I want in each regression, then use that repeatedly with different variables I want to compare.

The problem is that stargazer is printing tables with the name I gave the argument in the function (x), instead of the name of the actual variable (VariableA, etc.). That's making it so that I can't compare different models in the same stargazer table.

Any idea how to get stargazer to print the name of the variable I supplied to the argument, rather than the name of the argument? Screenshot of the output and code below.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlO7v.jpg

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(stargazer)

df <- data.frame(
  VariableA = (sample.int(100, 10000, replace = T)), 
  VariableB = (sample.int(75, 10000, replace = T)), 
  Outcome1 = (sample.int(10, 10000, replace = T)), 
  Outcome2 = (sample.int(10, 10000, replace = T)), 
  Category = (sample((LETTERS[1:3]), 10, replace = TRUE)))

model_function <- function(x=x, y=y){
  lm(y~x+Category, data = df)
}

a  <- model_function(df$VariableA, df$Outcome1)
b  <- model_function(df$VariableB, df$Outcome1)
c  <- model_function(df$VariableA, df$Outcome2)
d  <- model_function(df$VariableB, df$Outcome2)

e <- lm(Outcome1~VariableA+Category, data = df)
f <- lm(Outcome1~VariableB+Category, data = df)
g <- lm(Outcome2~VariableA+Category, data = df)
h <- lm(Outcome2~VariableB+Category, data = df)
```

```
{r, echo=F, results='asis'}

stargazer(a,b,c,d,
          title = "This one looks wrong",
          type = "html")

stargazer(e, f, g, h,
          title = "Desired output looks like this",
          type = "html")
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TomfM.png
```

Comment: Are you just trying to hard-code the `+Category` and `data = df` parts?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are passing a vector to the function instead of an expression that you could inject into the formula. Perhaps you could tell us what you would like to achieve so we can suggest a better workflow? At first glance, your first attempt (that doesn't work) looks more cumbersome than the one that does.

One alternative could be fixest:

```r
library(fixest)
mods <- feols(..("Outcome") ~ sw(VariableA, VariableB) + Category, data = df)
etable(mods)
#>                            mods.1            mods.2            mods.3
#> Dependent Var.:          Outcome1          Outcome1          Outcome2
#>                                                                      
#> Constant        5.487*** (0.0679) 5.584*** (0.0677) 5.565*** (0.0679)
#> VariableA        -0.0003 (0.0010)                    -0.0003 (0.0010)
#> CategoryB         0.0087 (0.0641)   0.0079 (0.0641)  -0.0464 (0.0642)
#> CategoryC         0.1068 (0.0785)   0.1070 (0.0785) -0.1712* (0.0786)
#> VariableB                         -0.0029* (0.0013)                  
#> _______________ _________________ _________________ _________________
#> S.E. type                     IID               IID               IID
#> Observations               10,000            10,000            10,000
#> R2                        0.00021           0.00069           0.00049
#> Adj. R2                  -8.56e-5           0.00039           0.00019
#> 
#>                            mods.4
#> Dependent Var.:          Outcome2
#>                                  
#> Constant        5.578*** (0.0678)
#> VariableA                        
#> CategoryB        -0.0465 (0.0642)
#> CategoryC       -0.1710* (0.0786)
#> VariableB        -0.0007 (0.0013)
#> _______________ _________________
#> S.E. type                     IID
#> Observations               10,000
#> R2                        0.00051
#> Adj. R2                   0.00021
#> ---
#> Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>